# Visual Studio 2010 bug in using controls!

Tags: visual-studio

I create a C# windows form application in visual studio 2010. I create some controls and darg them into my main form. Every time I change the controls, building of the project faild because the exe (output) file is locked (there is no any syntax error).
After above error I have to close VS and reopen the project.

My question is I make mistake or visual studio has a bug in this situation?

Thanks.

Comment: Watch out for circular dependencies.  Build + Clean and verify that it still builds.

Answer (score 2):

Is the executable running from the Debug or Release directory? You can't recompile it if the output is running, then Visual Studio won't be able to replace it.

Comment: When the app is running, you are right. but the app is not running.